Mongoid: Querying embedded (embeds_many) documents
These are my classes:
class Ticket
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :transitions
end

class Transition
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :ticket

  field :to, type: String
  field :created_at, type: DateTime
end

For example, I have a Ticket with the following transitions:
[#<Transition _id: 663b468deebb9d417d981152, to: "created", created_at: 2024-05-08 09:31:57.855 UTC>,
 #<Transition _id: 663b47cceebb9d417d981153, to: "solved", created_at: 2024-05-08 09:37:16.424 UTC>,
 #<Transition _id: 663b47ceeebb9d417d981154, to: "working", created_at: 2024-05-08 09:37:18.717 UTC>,
 #<Transition _id: 663b47d0eebb9d417d981155, to: "pending", created_at: 2024-05-08 09:37:20.989 UTC>]

I want to find tickets where the LAST transition has the following properties:
Ticket.where(:'transitions.to' => "solved", :"transitions.created_at".lte => Time.now - 24.hours)

How can I modify the query to match only the last transition?

After repeatedly hitting head against the wall, I was able to use aggregation pipeline and filter documents the way I needed them:
      Ticket.collection.aggregate(
        [
          {
            "$project": {
              _id: 1,
              transitions: {
                "$slice": [
                  "$transitions",
                  -1
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$match": {
              "transitions.created_at": {
                "$lte": Time.now.utc - 24.hours
              },
              "transitions.to": {
                "$in": states
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$project": {
              _id: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      ).to_a

I added 3 stages:

project docs with only the latest transition
filter out docs where transition matches my conditions
project docs with only id field

https://mongoplayground.net/p/UprsfaP0clE

Few doubts to clarify with you - 1. the first stage of this query gives only the latest transitions. However it may give the same for all tickets from the very beginning.   2. The primary criterion of this query may be the transitions in last 24 hours.  There is no need to go beyond this. Then it may make the query more performant. 3. If solved is an irreversible status, functionally it means so, then the query may be much more simpler. Irreversible means once a ticket has transitioned into 'solved' state, it cannot be go either beyond or below  to that status....

...if that is the case, then your original query itself may do the job, provided the criteria must be inside $elemMatch as this: test> t.find({"ticket_state_transitions": {$elemMatch:{to:'solved',created_at:{$lte:'2024-05-08 13:10:08.571 UTC'}}}},{_id:1});
[ { _id: ObjectId('663c8f2aacec08b90165fcea') } ]
